# Plot points for third data value on line in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame, Savings, with 3 columns like the following:

```
Templates      FTEs        PageTotal  
        1      54.87922      532900.4
      383      34.35612    15165274.1
      765      31.09695    16608751.6
     1147      29.32025    17553846.2
     1529      28.23367    18019766.2
     1911      27.52513    18346629.7
     2293      27.06843    18528129.5
     2675      26.75649    18660953.8
     3057      26.53630    18732909.4
     3439      26.37230    18793627.5
     3821      26.24649    18824156.0
     4203      26.14882    18880440.9
     4585      26.07402    18903224.3
     4967      26.01293    18917600.4
     5349      25.95397    18941023.6
     5731      25.90557    18958726.5
     6113      25.86892    18967352.1
     6495      25.84334    18976647.7
     6877      25.82275    18981660.5
     7259      25.81053    18984535.7
```

I am plotting the first two columns with the following command:

```
ggplot(data=Savings, aes(x=Templates, y=FTEs, color=variable)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=FTEs, col="FTEs"), size=1, color="dodgerblue3") +
    labs(x="Templates", y="FTEs") +
    scale_x_continuous(labels=scales::comma, breaks(0,7700,by=500)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,60,by=2))
```

I would like to plot a subset of the points from the third column, "PageTotal", on the same line, showing notations on the graph with the values from "PageTotal" for those points. Essentially, we want to be able to see the corresponding page total for the number of templates.

The PageTotal subset that is displayed can just be 5 evenly spaced values according to the Template numbers.

I am not sure the best way to accomplish this using ggplot2.

Edit:
So I have made it this far:

```
ggplot(data=Savings, aes(x=Templates, y=FTEs, color=variable)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=FTEs, col="FTEs"), size=1, color="dodgerblue3") +
    geom_point(data=Savings[seq(1,20,by=5),], aes(x=Templats, y=FTEs), color="red") +
    geom_text(data=Savings[seq(1,20,by=5),], aes(y=FTEs, label=format(round(PageTotal, 0), big.mark=",")), hjust=0, vjust=0, color="black") +
    labs(x="Templates", y="FTEs") +
    scale_x_continuous(labels=scales::comma, breaks(0,7700,by=500)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,60,by=2))
```

However, now the labels are too close together and run over the top of each other. Is there anyway to either rotate the labels, or position them alternately so they don't overlap?

Comment: There is no `value` or `variable` column in your dataframe. You missed out some processing code

Comment: I edited it to reference the column. In the actual graph I am plotting several different lines. In the geom_lines call it recognizes that aes(y=FTEs, ... replaces the "values" reference. I don't know if that's how it should be done, but it works that way for me.
The color=variable works the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new dataframe with the data you want to plot, then change the data argument in the layer. Here I `cut` the `Templates` column into 5 evenly sized groups, and keep the first row of each group.

```
library(tidyverse) 

Savings <- read.table(text = "
Templates      FTEs        PageTotal  
        1      54.87922      532900.4
      383      34.35612    15165274.1
      765      31.09695    16608751.6
     1147      29.32025    17553846.2
     1529      28.23367    18019766.2
     1911      27.52513    18346629.7
     2293      27.06843    18528129.5
     2675      26.75649    18660953.8
     3057      26.53630    18732909.4
     3439      26.37230    18793627.5
     3821      26.24649    18824156.0
     4203      26.14882    18880440.9
     4585      26.07402    18903224.3
     4967      26.01293    18917600.4
     5349      25.95397    18941023.6
     5731      25.90557    18958726.5
     6113      25.86892    18967352.1
     6495      25.84334    18976647.7
     6877      25.82275    18981660.5
     7259      25.81053    18984535.7", header = TRUE)


page_summary <- Savings %>% 
  mutate(Temp_group = cut(Templates, 5)) %>% # cut into groups
  group_by(Temp_group) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) # keep first from each group

ggplot(Savings, aes(x = Templates, y = FTEs, label = PageTotal)) +
  geom_line(color="dodgerblue3") + 
  geom_point(data = page_summary, size = 3) +
  geom_label(data = page_summary, hjust = 0, nudge_x = 120, nudge_y = 1) +
  labs(x="Templates", y="FTEs") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma, breaks = seq(0, 7700, by = 500)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 60, by = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. Sometimes the ggplot interface feels a bit magical.